# How to add number of seconds to current date using the time-rs crate

Tags: rust

I want to add `100` seconds to the current time. I'm using this [lib](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/)

```rust
use time::PrimitiveDateTime as DateTime;

pub fn after(start: DateTime) -> DateTime {
    start + 100 seconds // something like this to the start DateTime
}
```

Comment: `time::Duration::seconds(100)`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [`time::Duration`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.Duration.html), which can be added to a `PrimitiveDateTime`. The current time needs to be gotten from an `OffsetDateTime`, but can easily be used to construct your `start`:

```rust
use time::Duration;
use time::OffsetDateTime;
use time::PrimitiveDateTime as DateTime;

pub fn after(start: DateTime) -> DateTime {
    start + Duration::seconds(100)
}

fn main() {
    let now = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();
    let start = DateTime::new(now.date(), now.time());

    println!("{:?}", now);
    println!("{:?}", start);
    println!("{:?}", after(start));
}
```

I don't know if you have a reason for using `PrimitiveDateTime`, but it doesn't contain any time zone info, so I'd suggest replacing those since `OffsetDateTime` still contains the primitive, and is required to get the current time:

```rust
use time::Duration;
use time::OffsetDateTime as DateTime;

pub fn after(start: DateTime) -> DateTime {
    start + Duration::seconds(100)
}

fn main() {
    let now = DateTime::now_utc();

    println!("{:?}", now);
    println!("{:?}", after(now));
}
```